# How to make a navbar that works on all screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, navigation

Trying to just create a website with only knowledge of HTML/CSS and JavaScript for now (tired of learning, wanted to do something), but with the navbar I am having trouble with keeping the navbar spaced out correctly on all screen types.

For example, if my Firefox browser is full screen then it works find, but if I snap it to half screen then the navigation text (Home, About, etc) all start stacking onto each other.

Didn't really know specifically what I was asking for, so Googling was not working.

Any help, or more specifically any tutorials or topics about this to look into? I saw a lot of jQuery and Bootstraps when trying to Google more about it, but I don't really know those yet.

Comment: If you can put up your code, it would be easy to guide you through.

Comment: Bootstrap is easy to implement and no need to learning anything new :) Just a copy and paste of code. Read from here... http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Also you can use Media queries, any way put your code, give a jsfiddle or something like that, so we can help u in details

Answer (score 0):

Look in to bootstrap, that can help you as it provides a frame-work of CSS for you to work with, including responsive navbars.

or try

```
.cssclassname {
width: 100%;
}
```

That would set the width to 100% screen size.